# Live table edit display field(s) from other mySQL tables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a table that works like this: http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/editable.html without the header sorting, page changing, and search. I have another functionality that allows me to add a row. All of this is done on the same page. The data is drawn directly from a database. I wrote the code generic so it could be used for any table I want to display.

However, I have came across a problem. Let's say an end-user wants to see a list of houses. This list would be drawn from a houses database. Each house has an owner. There is also an owners table. Each owner has an id (primary_key). In the houses table the owner field uses the owner's id to identify the proper owner. Here is where the problem arises. Once the data from the houses table is displayed the owner, for instance, shows up as an id number. Obviously, to the end-user it either is meaningless or at least annoying. I would like to have, in this case the owner's name, the field that is in question to show instead of a "seemingly" meaningless field. I'm posting the relevant code for my predicament.

Also, can I change mySQL booleans through jQuery? What I mean by that is if, for example, a house is not up for rent so the `for_rent` flag is set to `0` for `FALSE`. The table will show `0`, as that is what is in the table. Can I change that through jQuery? (Find the `0`s or `1`s and make them say `true` or `false`? Any suggestions as to a direction for answering these questions would be great. Thanks.

Here is the relevant code:

PHP to display table:

```
public function displayTable($table)
{
    //connect to DB
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    echo "<table id='table' border='1'>";   //start an HTML table

    $dbtable = $table;
    $fields =array();
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$dbtable);

    //fill fields array with fields from table in database
    while ($x = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $fields[] = $x['Field'];
    }

    $fieldsnum = count($fields);    //number of fields in array

    //create table header from dbtable fields
    foreach ($fields as $f)
    {
        echo "<th>".$f."</th>";
    }

    //create table rows from dbtable rows
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM ".$dbtable);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rowid = $row[$fields[0]];

        echo "<tr class='edit_tr' id='".$rowid."'>";
        foreach ($fields as $f) 
        { 
            echo "<td class='edit_td' data-field='".$f."'><span id='".$rowid."' class='text'>".$row[$f]."</span>
            <input type='text' value='".$row[$f]."' class='editbox' id='".$rowid."' data-field='".$f."'/> </td>"; 
        }
        $rowid++;

        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";    //close the HTML table

    $recordid = $rowid;

    //close connection
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

jQuery to live edit table:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".edit_td").click(function()
        {
            $(this).children(".text").hide();
            $(this).children(".editbox").show();                

        }).children('.editbox').change(function()
            {
                var table = $('body').attr('id');
                var id=$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
                var field=$(this).data('field');
                var text=$(this).val();
                var dataString = {table:table, id:id, field:field, text:text};
                if (field != text)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "classes/table_edit_ajax.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                        window.location.reload(true);
                    }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Enter something.');
                }
            });

        // Edit input box click action
        $(".editbox").mouseup(function() 
        {
            return false
        });

        // Outside click action
        $(document).mouseup(function()
        {
            $(".editbox").hide();
            $(".text").show();
        });

    });
```

jQuery to live add row:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".add").click(function()
        {
            var fieldArray = [];

            var $table = $("#table");
            var $lastRow = $table.find("tr:last");
            var $dataFields = $lastRow.find("td");

            $dataFields.each(function() {
                fieldArray.push($(this).attr("data-field"));
                });

            $("#table").each(function()
            {

                var $table = $(this);
                var id=$('#table tr:last').attr('id');
                var $tr = $("#table").children('tr');
                var tablename = $('body').attr('id');
                var n = $('tr:last td', this).length;
                var tds = '<tr class="edit_tr" id="' + id++ + '">';

                for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    tds += '<td class="edit_td" data-field="' + fieldArray[i] +
                    '"><span id="'+ id +'" class="text">&nbsp;</span><input type="text" class="editbox" id="' +
                    id + '" data-field="' + fieldArray[i] + '"/>&nbsp;</td>';
                    console.log('id: ' + id);
                }

                tds += '</tr>';

                var dataString = {table:tablename, id:id};

                if($('tbody', this).length > 0)
                {
                    $('tbody', this).append(tds);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "classes/table_new_ajax.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html)
                        {
                            window.location.reload(true);
                        }
                    });
                }else {
                    $(this).append(tds);
                }

            }); 
        });
    });
```

Comment: This sounds like an entirely new animal to tackle. I am not familiar with ORM. Is it similar to nth tier application, business objects, etc? I am familiar with those in ASP.NET, but have no idea how to go about something like that in PHP. Would it be better for me to just place the `displayTable` code inside each page that needs it and alter the queries specifically for that table? Or is the ORM option preferable? I ask because frankly I am limited on time. Thanks so much for the suggestion.

Comment: This type of replacement from an id to a different field requires some exceptional logic in your query (so I don't see reuse being possible).  You would want to select OwnerId as OwnerName and join the Houses and Owners tables.  Booleans on the other hand could be replaced consistently by a true/false value by the front end (javascript) without changes to your query or code.

Answer (score 1):

you will probably want to extend your generic function for generating the html table to include a joined db table if necessary, though that would get messy, so, create a new function for when you need to join 2 db tables.
The sql for retrieving the owners name into the list of houses would go something like (with a guess at what your field names are):
    select a.housename,a.street,a.for_rent,b.name from houses a, owners b where a.owner_id=b.id

Comment: This is what I was thinking. Someone suggested ORMs, but deleted their comment. I've been googling it and feel like it's a rabbit I don't want to chase. With around 10 tables this will be used with, I feel that making them page specific instead of general is worth it for the functionality I'm looking for. I'll try it out tomorrow. Thanks.